# How to install header-only C++ library using autotools?

Tags: autotools, automake

The library that I'm working on is a header-only library. It has the following structure:

```
+-- Makefile.am
+-- include
|   +-- header1.h
|   +-- header2.h
+-- tests
|   +-- test1.c
|   +-- test2.c
|   +-- Makefile.am
```

In `tests/Makefile.am`, `bin_PROGRAMS = test1 test2`.

When I did `./configure && make && make install`, only the test executables were installed in `${PREFIX}/bin`. I have two questions:

1. How can I install the two headers during `make install` to `${PREFIX}/include`?
2. How can I avoid installing the executables during `make install` but still be able to compile them during `make`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How can I install the two headers during make install to ${PREFIX}/include?

Every file you want to install must be named to Automake, or else handled by a custom target.  The primary for C and C++ header files is `HEADERS`, and `includedir` is one of the standard directory variables.  One way to get the headers installed, then, is to add this to the top-level `Makefile.am`:

```
include_HEADERS = include/header1.h include/header2.h
```

Note well that the `include/` in each file name is the path to that header in the source directory, relative to the `Makefile.am` in which it appears.  It has no other significance in that declaration.  In particular, the installed files will be `$(includedir)/header1.h` and `$(includedir)/header2.h`, not `$(includedir)/include/...`.  That is, Automake bases the target filename on the value of the corresponding directory variable and the *basename* of the specified path, which has the result you want.  (Prefixing the variable name with `nobase_` would cause Automake to preserve the relative path portion.)

Note also that the value of `$(includedir)` is `$(prefix)/include` by default, but you can override that with the appropriate argument to `configure`.

> 2. How can I avoid installing the executables during make install but still be able to compile them during make?

The declaration

> ```
> bin_PROGRAMS = test1 test2
> ```

says not only that `test1` and `test2` are executables to be built, but *also* that they are to be installed in `$(bindir)` by `make install`.  If instead you want them built by `make` by default but never installed, then use the special prefix `noinst_`, which serves exactly that purpose:

```
noinst_PROGRAMS = test1 test2
```

Alternatively, if you are using Automake's built-in support for building and running test suites, and these binaries are in fact intended for that purpose, then you should consider instead using the `check_` prefix:

```
check_PROGRAMS = test1 test2
```

That will cause those programs to be built (at need) by `make check`, but not by default, and never installed.  Where applicable, that clarifies the intention, and perhaps saves you a bit of time on some of your builds.

For a more comprehensive explanation of these matters, you should consult the AutoMake manual, especially its section about the "[uniform naming scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Uniform)".